# How to fix "xcor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' error in Python

Tags: python, class, turtle-graphics, superclass

I am simply trying to refer to the turtle's location from the turtle class I created. I feel what I'm doing is theoretically incorrect but it looks as if it would work. Maybe this error is beyond me but I am just not sure.

I have tried other methods to placing turtles but they became extremely complex and unusable.

```
class Maze_wall(Turtle):

    def __init__(self, x_loc, y_loc):
       super().__init__()
       self.color("#ffffff")
       self.penup()
       self.speed(0)
       self.shape("square")
       self.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.95, stretch_len=0.95)
       self.goto(x_loc, y_loc)
       self.showturtle()
```

Above is my turtle class and below I try to reference the turtles x and y coordinates.

```
def wall_right():
    Maze_wall(Maze_wall.xcor(), Maze_wall.ycor())
def wall_left():
    Maze_wall(Maze_wall.xcor(), Maze_wall.ycor())
def wall_up():
    Maze_wall(Maze_wall.xcor(), Maze_wall.ycor())
def wall_down():
    Maze_wall(Maze_wall.xcor(), Maze_wall.ycor())
```

My goal is for each function to place a turtle based off of the turtles current location.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** you're invoking `.xcor()` on a turtle subclass instead of a turtle instance.

**Longer answer:** you seem to be mixing up the turtle you're using to lay out the maze with the turtles that will become the walls of the maze.  You can't ask a wall it's location before it exists.  What I would have expected is code more like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Maze_wall(Turtle):

    def __init__(self, x_loc, y_loc):
        super().__init__(visible=False)

        self.shape('square')
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('black')
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.95, stretch_len=0.95)
        self.goto(x_loc, y_loc)
        self.showturtle()

def wall_right(turtle):
        return Maze_wall(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor())

builder = Turtle(visible=False)
builder.penup()

walls = []

for _ in range(4):
    builder.forward(100)
    wall = wall_right(builder)
    walls.append(wall)
    builder.left(90)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```